# What is an algorithm I can use to program an image compare routine to detect changes (like a person coming into the frame of a web cam)?

Tags: image, image-processing, detection

I have a web cam that takes a picture every N seconds. This gives me a collection of images of the same scene over time. I want to process that collection of images as they are created to identify events like someone entering into the frame, or something else large happening. I will be comparing images that are adjacent in time and fixed in space - the same scene at different moments of time.

I want a reasonably sophisticated approach. For example, naive approaches fail for outdoor applications. If you count the number of pixels that change, for example, or the percentage of the picture that has a different color or grayscale value, that will give false positive reports every time the sun goes behind a cloud or the wind shakes a tree.

I want to be able to positively detect a truck parking in the scene, for example, while ignoring lighting changes from sun/cloud transitions, etc.

I've done a number of searches, and found a few survey papers (Radke et al, for example) but nothing that actually gives algorithms that I can put into a program I can write.

Comment: Not sure of the names, but I believe OpenCV is a library that has algorithms for this stuff.

Comment: Are you looking for any particular language? I was thinking about writing this a little different than your specification. The input would be a sequence of images and the output would be a sequence of sequences where the image was in transition. Ex: taking the first item would give you the first set of images where a truck is passing through. Will that work?

Comment: Any language - I can read anything and write in most of them. I'm after an algorithm I can use.

Comment: I've heard [zoneminder](http://www.zoneminder.com/) is a good solution to motion detection. My teacher was telling me that it starts recording only when it detects movement. I believe you can also set up specific parts of the view in which to detect movement.  It's open source for Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use color spectroanalisys, without luminance: when the Sun goes down for a while, you will get similar result, colors does not change (too much).
2. Don't go for big changes, but quick changes. If the luminance of the image changes -10% during 10 min, it means the usual evening effect. But when the change is -5%, 0, +5% within seconds, its a quick change.
3. Don't forget to adjust the reference values.
4. Split the image to smaller regions. Then, when all the regions change same way, you know, it's a global change, like an eclypse or what, but if only one region's parameters are changing, then something happens there.
5. Use masks to create smart regions. If you're watching a street, filter out the sky, the trees (blown by wind), etc. You may set up different trigger values for different regions. The regions should overlap.
6. A special case of the region is the line. A line (a narrow region) contains less and more homogeneous pixels than a flat area. Mark, say, a green fence, it's easy to detect wheter someone crosses it, it makes bigger change in the line than in a flat area.
7. If you can, change the IRL world. Repaint the fence to a strange color to create a color spectrum, which can be identified easier. Paint tags to the floor and wall, which can be OCRed by the program, so you can detect wheter something hides it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are trying to solve is very interesting indeed!

I think that you would need to attack it in parts:

As you already pointed out, a sudden change in illumination can be problematic. This is an indicator that you probably need to achieve some sort of illumination-invariant representation of the images you are trying to analyze.

There are plenty of techniques lying around, one I have found very useful for illumination invariance (applied to face recognition) is **DoG filtering** (Difference of Gaussians)

The idea is that you first convert the image to gray-scale. Then you generate two blurred versions of this image by applying a gaussian filter,  one a little bit more blurry than the first one.  (you could use a 1.0 sigma and a 2.0 sigma in a gaussian filter respectively) Then you subtract from the less-blury image, the pixel intensities of the more-blurry image.  This operation enhances edges and produces a similar image regardless of strong illumination intensity variations. These steps can be very easily performed using OpenCV (as others have stated).  This technique has been applied and documented [here](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/54/86/74/PDF/TT07.pdf).
This paper adds an extra step involving contrast equalization, In my experience this is only needed if you want to obtain "visible" images from the DoG operation (pixel values tend to be very low after the DoG filter and are veiwed as black rectangles onscreen), and performing a histogram equalization is an acceptable substitution if you want to be able to see the effect of the DoG filter.

Once you have illumination-invariant images you could focus on the detection part.  If your problem can afford having a static camera that can be trained for a certain amount of time,  then you could use a strategy similar to alarm motion detectors. Most of them work with an average thermal image - basically they record the average temperature of the "pixels" of a room view, and trigger an alarm when the heat signature varies greatly from one "frame" to the next.   Here you wouldn't be working with temperatures, but with average, light-normalized pixel values.  This would allow you to build up with time which areas of the image tend to have movement (e.g. the leaves of a tree in a windy environment), and which areas are fairly stable in the image.  **Then you could trigger an alarm when a large number of pixles already flagged as stable have a strong variation from one frame to the next one.**

If you can't afford training your camera view, then I would suggest you take a look at the **TLD tracker** of [Zdenek Kalal](http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/Z.Kalal/tld.html). His research is focused on object tracking with a single frame as training.  You could probably use the semistatic view of the camera (with no foreign objects present) as a starting point for the tracker and flag a detection when the TLD tracker (a grid of points where local motion flow is estimated using the Lucas-Kanade algorithm) fails to track a large amount of gridpoints from one frame to the next. This scenario would probably allow even a panning camera to work as the algorithm is very resilient to motion disturbances.

Hope this pointers are of some help.  Good Luck and enjoy the journey!   =D

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for [Template Matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching)

Also i would suggest you to look on to [Open CV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)

Comment: @Kishor_Kundan, Any particular part of OpenCV? I don't want object detection, because I'm not trying to detect an object in an image; I'm comparing to images adjacent in time to look for significant differences caused by a new object in the frame. Also, Template Matching is a way to find particular, pre-defined objects (the "templates") in an image. The example shows finding a cat's face in a picture of a cat. It works if you know what you're looking for - I don't know what I'm looking for, just a significant change.

Comment: @DMac : Your users will have to explicitly specify for what you will be running template matching. If you can't afford this you will have to end up using object detection anyways, especially for the part "some one entering in".. 
I am not sure how this will work as i have never tested this but may be "cvAbsDiff" from opencv can be used. I googled around and someone has done something similar "http://sublimated.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/image-difference-with-opencv/" I haven't tested it, but it is some sort of leads to you.

Answer (score 1):

We had to contend with many of these issues in our interactive installations. It's tough to not get false positives without being able to control some of your environment (sounds like you will have some degree of control). In the end we looked at combining some techniques and we created an open piece of software named OpenTSPS (Open Toolkit for Sensing People in Spaces - http://www.opentsps.com). You can look at the C++ source in github (https://github.com/labatrockwell/openTSPS/).

We use ‘progressive background relearn’ to adjust to the changing background over time. Progressive relearning is particularly useful in variable lighting conditions – e.g. if lighting in a space changes from day to night. This in combination with blob detection works pretty well and the only way we have found to improve is to use 3D cameras like the kinect which cast out IR and measure it.

There are other algorithms that might be relevant, like SURF (http://achuwilson.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/object-detection-using-surf-in-opencv-part-1/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SURF) but I don't think it will help in your situation unless you know exactly the type of thing you are looking for in the image.

Sounds like a fun project. Best of luck.

Comment: Yow - very interesting answer; thank you very much. I'll look at your website closely.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the standard measures like [Mean Squared Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error), for eg. to find out the difference between two consecutive images. If the MSE is beyond a certain threshold, you know that there is some motion.

Also read about [Motion Estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_estimation).

Comment: That is one of the simplistic approaches that doesn't work. If the sun goes behind a cloud, *all* the pixels change. But nothing came into the frame, so I shouldn't register a change. I expect that I will need something that understands that things in a picture take up a contiguous region, and that the shapes of the regions in the picture have to change - for example, the image of a truck driving into the driveway or a person walking into frame occludes what was there before and creates a new region in the image.

Comment: See the approach  here, remove background both reference and image , compute grays diffs them find countours in diff and check they are big enough https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/

Answer (score 0):

if you know that the image will remain reletivly static I would reccomend:

1) look into neural networks. you can use them to learn what defines someone within the image or what is a non-something in the image.

2) look into motion detection algorithms, they are used all over the place.

3) is you camera capable of thermal imaging? if so it may be worthwile to look for hotspots in the images. There may be existing algorithms to turn your webcam into a thermal imager.

Comment: A thermal imaging device, such as a thermal imager or infrared imager, detects the infrared radiation or heat emitted by objects. Based on these detections, it creates a 'thermal profile' or heat map of the area in focus. ?? Can I use my usb webcam as thermal.imager it would save me a couple  of hundreds bucks and the long search for non existent drivers to it